# finding most recent value for a specific month in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im having a mysql problem, I am trying to find the most current value for a specific month, the entire table schema and data can be seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/770f7/10), the query that I have written to accomplish this is as follows:

```
max(case 
when Month(py.pay_date) = 8
then amount  end) previous_month_amount
```

However It is not returning the correct values, in this case the correct values should be:

```
name  previous_month_amount
Carl      30
Mark      40
```

Hope I made the question clear enough, and thank you for your help.

Comment: And what if two payments are made on the latest date?

Comment: the if shows the payments made..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as "What is the last payment made in each month?"  If you answer this, then you can get the appropriate "last payment" just by choosing the right month.  The following query does this:

```
select p.name, lp.yr, lp.mon, pa.amount
from persons p join
     (select person_id, year(pay_date) as yr, month(pay_date) as mon,
             max(pay_date) as max_pay_date
      from payment
      group by person_id, year(pay_date), month(pay_date)
     ) lp
     on p.id = lp.person_id join
     payment pa
     on p.id = pa.person_id and
        pa.pay_date = lp.max_pay_date
group by p.name, lp.yr, lp.mon, pa.amount
```

Comment: my main problem is I was actually trying to incorporate it with the other queries